# Angular2 Error when using angular2-img-cropper in Visual Studio Type FileReader is not assignable to type FileReader

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I just tried to explore plugin angular2-img-cropper (https://github.com/cstefanache/angular2-img-cropper) and added some of the sample code from the plunker https://embed.plnkr.co/V91mKCNkBQZB5QO2MUP4/ to my app.

But when I try to compile my app in Visual Studio 2015, its giving below error:

```
Type FileReader is not assignable to type FileReader. Property onloadend is missing in type FileReader
```

The actual error is in the below piece of code from above plunker:

```
fileChangeListener($event) {
        var image:any = new Image();
        var file:File = $event.target.files[0];
        var myReader:FileReader = new FileReader();
        var that = this;
        myReader.onloadend = function (loadEvent:any) {
            image.src = loadEvent.target.result;
            that.cropper.setImage(image);

        };

        myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

Can anyone please guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to replace with event listener:

```
fileReader.addEventListener('loadend', function(loadEvent:any){
    image.src = loadEvent.target.result;
    that.setImage(image);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Cornel, I upgraded to the Typescript 2 beta and it fixed that error.

Comment: I have noticed another issue, the cropper doesn't seem to return the correct coordinates of the cropped image if the height of the image is less than the canvas height.

Comment: Please file an issue in the cropper github repo so we can track it.